# Passing unit test through different threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, nunit

I have a performance issue that is only visible when my app is handling loads of data.

Trying to make a unit test to ensure good performance is not viable because even in the best of cases it is going to take over 5 minutes to run a single time.

I want to ensure that my performance is not getting worse, but I don't want the rest of the tests having to wait over 5 minutes (or more) to start. My first attempt would be to make this test to run on a separate thread, but this imply that the [Test] will always pass as valid.

Does NUnit support running different tests in separated threads at the same time?

Maybe what I need is not a unit test, I will be glad to hear suggestions.

Comment: Side note: something that runs for 5 minutes is not normally called "unit test"...

Comment: Should I call it "integration test" better?

I understand the term abuse right there. And that's why I think there should be something more appropriate to use instead of NUnit  (or any unit testing suite) to guarantee good performance and "comfortable".

Answer (score 2):

Unit tests should be runned very fast (much less than 1 sec.) and should be runned in memory, so if we talk about 5 mins. and loading data, we are talking about integration test. You should separate that test from unit ones by creating new project for integration tests using (for example) following convention:

- Project.Tests.Unit
- Project.Tests.Integration

You can read more about differences between unit test & integration test at:
http://www.typemock.com/unit-tests-integration-tests.

Answer (score 1):

NUnit also support "Categories" on your test fixtures.  So if you make a new test fixture with a different category, you can then specify what categories you want to run in your suite.  This is a great way to decide what types of tests you want to run together.  And you can build up different suites to run different groups of tests.

http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=category&r=2.2